# How do I set the anomaly score in crs-setup.conf?

Tags: linux, nginx, mod-security

I am using v3.0.0 of CRS with ModSecurity set to DetectionOnly mode and the nginx connector.
I want to set the anomaly score to 100 or so to fine-tune the settings, but I can't see where or how to do that.
Looking in crs-setup.conf

nginx 1.18.0 if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anomaly scores for each severity level are set by default under rule ID `900100` in `crs-setup.conf`. If you want to modify these values you can un-comment and edit it.

Example:

```
SecAction \
 "id:900100,\
  phase:1,\
  nolog,\
  pass,\
  t:none,\
  setvar:tx.critical_anomaly_score=100,\
  setvar:tx.error_anomaly_score=75,\
  setvar:tx.warning_anomaly_score=50,\
  setvar:tx.notice_anomaly_score=25"
```

You can also play around with the threshold at which requests/responses get denied by modifying rule ID `900110`, also in `crs-setup.conf`.

Example:

```
SecAction \
 "id:900110,\
  phase:1,\
  nolog,\
  pass,\
  t:none,\
  setvar:tx.inbound_anomaly_score_threshold=200,\
  setvar:tx.outbound_anomaly_score_threshold=300"
```

Comment: #slightly_toasted - thank you - I had no clue!

Comment: Could you specify the meaning of those values? What is a normal anomaly score, and should we lower or raise that value to make ModSecurity less sensitive?